# What would be the best class to use for the No Child Left Behind achievement?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

I am about to start a second stick of truth play through and I'm going to try to get the achievement where none of your party members are dead at the end of the battle.  I am wondering what people think would be the best class to use in terms of dispatching enemies quickly.

Comment: Please, add the information about the class that you played, and what difficult you confront, so we can help. We aren't a forum to discuss class. We give you answer that will provide solid information that will lead to the solution that you want.

Comment: @Michel Do you have *any* familiarity with the game in question? The question as written was perfectly fine. He's asking whether any class is best suited to pursuing a particular achievement, with very specific requirements. There are only four classes, and the differences between them are relatively small. It's a perfectly reasonably scoped question, and doesn't need to be narrowed or sculpted in any way.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz just for reading and videos, so far. Also, asking "what class I should use to do this" without saying nothing about what you have tried so far, in my opinion is still a question that can be improved. He played at least once before, he can say what he found more challenge, this helps with answers that can provide extra and more valuable information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect to targeting this achievement, [there isn't a huge amount of difference between the classes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159503/what-benefits-does-being-a-jew-give-me?rq=1).

The one thing that may significantly impact your quest for this achievement is the fact that if your buddy dies, *if you can revive them before the end of the fight*, you're still on track for the achievement. What that means is that you *may* want to build your character and select skills in such a way as to minimize your use of debuffs or Damage Over Time effects. (This has the side effect, incidentally, of making much of the game *much, much, harder*, for what it's worth, so I'm not sure I recommend going all in on the strategy - easier to reload, IMO.) This will allow you to make combat a bit more predictable, at the expense of it lasting longer. Incidentally, the class best suited to avoiding the application of DoT's -  the Fighter -  is also the class with access to the widest variety of abilities that can lower your opponents Attack, which is also useful for pursuing this achievement.

Another option is to focus more on *preventing* foes from acting. In this case, the Mage has access to a Stun from right near the beginning of the game, and later, gains access to the only innate Slow effect - which can be very useful.

Finally, the Jew and Thief both have access to abilities that can apply 'Pissed Off' to targets; this functions as a taunt of sorts, forcing enemies to attack your character instead of your Buddy. (Do note, however, that the Jew gains access to this at a *much* lower level than the thief).

Really though, all of these differences are pretty minor. What matters more is your consumable use, and willingness to reload if things do go a little pear shaped. Every class has the ability to do lots of damage, and once you get to a high enough level to kill a mob in one attack, (the Sucker Punch perk helps) the Swat Helmet and some smart use of your 'Shoot' skill on the map will mean that you can end many fights before an enemy even has a chance to try to hit your buddy.